# Cambiar el estado de un componentes desde otro fichero con onChange y usestate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, usestate

He empezado una aplicación utilizando el hook usestate. El problema me surge al crear mi primer componente reutilizable que es un formulario, el cual es invocado por el componente login().

El componente login envía por props todas los atributos de los inputs que se tienen que renderizar modalform. Los inputs se crean con React.createcomponent. En uno de los atributos le paso la función onChange.

Este onChange además dee recoger el eevent.target.value de dicho evento, llama al hook useState para cambiar el estado correspondiente.

¿Qué pasa?

Pues que se ejeecutra TODO correctamente pero el setState de la función onChange no se ejectua. Ya he probado llamar el setState con una función onClick pasada por props igual que la de onChange y si que funciona con ONCLICK !!! A ver si mee he logrado explicar. Os paso los códigos de los dos componentes.

export default function Login() {

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState("")   const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

 

 const onChangeNombre = (event)=>{
     const val1 = event.target.value
     setUser(val1)
     console.log(user)
 }

const onChangePassword = async (event)=>{
  const val2 = await event.target.value
  setPassword(val2)
  console.log(password)   }

const [inputs ,setInputs] = useState([{ "type":"text",
                                        "name": "Usuario",
                                        "onchange": onChangeNombre},
                                        { "type":"password",
                                        "name": "Contraseña",
                                        "onchange": onChangePassword}])   return (
<Box>
    <ModalForm 
      title="Logeate" 
      textoBoton="Login" 
      inputs={inputs}
      />  
</Box>   ) }
```

El otro componente es:

```
export default function ModalForm({title, textoBoton, inputs}) {
  let valueInputs = [...inputs]


 return (

<div>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <form id="form">
      {valueInputs.map(e => React.createElement("input", {type: e.type,
                                                          placeholder: e.name,
                                                          onChange: e.onchange}))}
      <BotonPrimario textoBoton={textoBoton} />
      
    </form>
</div>
```

Cuando llama a la función a través del evento onChange se recibe correctamente el e.target.value pero no se ejecuta el setUser.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Qué significa `pero no se ejecuta el setUser` para tí? Qué estás intentando que pase. Lee [example] para que podamos entender qué esperas

Comment: Pues que cuando se ejecuta la función onChangeNombre el estado no cambia. La intención es guardar el usuario y contraseña en 2 estados para luego hacer la búsqueda en la base de datos